# Failed to compile Network Manager 0.9.4

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, compiling

After upgrading to 12.04 I needed to re-compile Network Manager to the version 0.9.4.0 again. However with the version 9.4.0 I faced with the error during compilation with libdns-manager:

```
$ make
...
Making all in dns-manager
make[4]: Вхожу у каталог "/home/stasevych/install/network-manager/nm0.9.4.0/network-manager-0.9.4.0/src/dns-manager"
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/logging -I../../libnm-util -I../../libnm-util -I../../src -I../../include -I../../include -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -DLOCALSTATEDIR=\"/usr/local/var\"   -Wall -std=gnu89 -g -O2 -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wundef -Werror -MT libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.Tpo -c -o libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.lo `test -f 'nm-dns-manager.c' || echo './'`nm-dns-manager.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/logging -I../../libnm-util -I../../libnm-util -I../../src -I../../include -I../../include -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DLOCALSTATEDIR=\"/usr/local/var\" -Wall -std=gnu89 -g -O2 -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wundef -Werror -MT libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.Tpo -c nm-dns-manager.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.o
mv -f .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.Tpo .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-manager.Plo
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/logging -I../../libnm-util -I../../libnm-util -I../../src -I../../include -I../../include -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/libnl3   -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -DLOCALSTATEDIR=\"/usr/local/var\"   -Wall -std=gnu89 -g -O2 -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wundef -Werror -MT libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.Tpo -c -o libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.lo `test -f 'nm-dns-dnsmasq.c' || echo './'`nm-dns-dnsmasq.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/logging -I../../libnm-util -I../../libnm-util -I../../src -I../../include -I../../include -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/libnl3 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -DLOCALSTATEDIR=\"/usr/local/var\" -Wall -std=gnu89 -g -O2 -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wundef -Werror -MT libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.Tpo -c nm-dns-dnsmasq.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.o
nm-dns-dnsmasq.c: In function 'update':
nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:274:2: error: passing argument 1 of 'g_slist_copy' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror]
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gslist.h:82:10: note: expected 'struct GSList *' but argument is of type 'const struct GSList *'
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [libdns_manager_la-nm-dns-dnsmasq.lo] Помилка 1
make[4]: Залишаю каталог "/home/stasevych/install/network-manager/nm0.9.4.0/network-manager-0.9.4.0/src/dns-manager"
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Помилка 1
make[3]: Залишаю каталог "/home/stasevych/install/network-manager/nm0.9.4.0/network-manager-0.9.4.0/src"
make[2]: *** [all] Помилка 2
make[2]: Залишаю каталог "/home/stasevych/install/network-manager/nm0.9.4.0/network-manager-0.9.4.0/src"
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Помилка 1
make[1]: Залишаю каталог "/home/stasevych/install/network-manager/nm0.9.4.0/network-manager-0.9.4.0"
make: *** [all] Помилка 2
```

Has anybody faced with the similar errors? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but seems like `gslist.h` in the path `usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gslist.h` got changed.

It is expected to have breaking API changes in development version.
Why not use the package from ubuntu -> [network-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/network-manager) [image: Install network-manager].

Package URL : http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/network-manager

Comment: Hi. Changed with which version?.. The standard version of network-manager doesn't support wimax interface, which I really need.

Comment: It changed with ubuntu update.

Comment: Yes, it is the last update from yesterday.